# JS RegExp union of expressions

Tags: javascript

tell me how to unite the two expressions into one.
I want to use in the user's validator in angular 4

```
forbiddenValidator (control: FormControl) {
     let login = control.value as string;
     if (login && login.length> 0) {
       if (login.match (/ ^ [0-9] / g) .length> 0) {
         return {
           forbidden: true
         }
       }
       if (login.match (/ [^ A-Z0-9] / gi) .length> 0) {
         return {
           forbidden: true
         }
       }
     }
     return null;
   }
```

Comment: what do extra spaces mean inside your regexps? what is the logic behind this check? could you describe it with examples?

Comment: I think that is formatting issue but not sure. OP can tell

Comment: gaps inside it's just so the text was adjusted when creating a theme. they are not in fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|` operator

```
 regex = /regex1|regex2/gi
```